Educational Welsh Program from the Early Nineties with an Alien
Okay, so this may be a long shot, but I was recently asked about a TV program that a friend of mine remembered watching when we were in school.  I remembered the exact same program, but could not remember the name of the program.  Any ideas please?
The program was an educational program for learning Welsh.
It centered around an alien (humanoid) who landed somewhere in Wales and learned Welsh as he went about his business.  Every episode he would return to his ship and go through what he learnt that day on the main console of the ship.
I remember our teacher in school would record the program at home and then show it in school the following week.  This would have been around 1992-4.
The program was live action, between 20 and 30 mins long each week.
I believe the main character had short blonde hair and usually wore some kind of silvery grey "spacesuit".

Does the name Stabec ring a bell?

Me and my friends were trying to find it as well, we remembered it was called "Stabec" and we knew it was right as we all instantly remembered it. We were disappointed to find out that there is no information on it or any stills of it on the web. At least we know the name though. Glad I could help anyway.
EDIT: From a blog post about schools programming in the 80s-90s:

The other great Welsh offering was Stabec. This show was a serialised drama about a teenage alien who had fallen from space. Somehow, he managed to have impeccable English skills but decided that he would be better off learning Welsh. He even had a catchphrase - a robotic "DOES. NOT. REGISTER". He made friends with a teenage boy and girl (I thought she was rather foxy when I was fifteen). These two humans would (rather rudely) speak nothing but Welsh when in his company, so he spent most of each episode walking around Cardiff with a very confused look on his face.


Belter.  Thank you very much.

You might be looking for Muzzy.

According to this site there was a run of Welsh language episodes released by the BBC, that ran from 1991 to 1993.
This fits the time period, and the subject matter you listed in your question.

Sorry, but it wasn't an animation.

@ChrisHarland Oh well, guess it's not Muzzy then... Could you please add the detail that it was a live action show to your question, it might help others find what you're looking for and avoid having them look into animated shows like I did.
